# How do I fix "the specified path X:\config.msi is unavailable when uninstalling

Tags: visual-studio-2019, installation-package

I am trying to create an installer package for an app (C#). I installed the VS 2019 (Community) Installation package, added my app's EXE, a DLL and some folders. And I did create the Setup.Exe (and app.msi) and it did run but it failed to install some folders.

When I try to uninstall this installer app in Control Panel. I get 'X:\Config.msi is unavailable. (I did the trial installation on my X:\ drive)

Whether that folder exists or not I get the same error.

I do not know where to look for 'X:\Config.msi' and why would be unavailable even though it exists? That is, I can create this folder but that doesn't solve the problem.

That string does not exist in the Installer application. Or any place I can find.